# Can either a Chrome Extension or Chrome App access a user's installed program?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Can I access a program on a user's computer through either a Chrome Extension, or a Chrome App?

For example, suppose I have a program that edits photos, would I be able to embed the editor into the Extension or App so that the use doesn't have to right click the photo, save to disc, open it in the editor, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [FAQ](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/faq.html) for Google Extensions:

> **[What UI controls can I create for my
>   extension?](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/faq.html#faq-dev-05)**
>
> Extensions use HTML and CSS
>   to define their user interfaces, so
>   you can use standard form controls to
>   build your UI, or style the interface
>   with CSS, as you would a web page.
>   Additionally, your extension may add
>   buttons to the Chrome browser itself.
>   See browser actions and page actions
>   for more information.
>
> [Can I load DLLs in my extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/faq.html#faq-dev-06)?
>
> Yes,
>   using the [NPAPI interface](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/npapi.html). Because of
>   the possibility for abuse, though, we
>   will review your extension before
>   hosting it in the Google Chrome
>   Extensions Gallery or Chrome Web
>   Store.

Based on the FAQ, I would come to the conclusion that although you can call installed dll's you can only use the returned values.  You can not implement custom controls or embed a program inside an extension.

I'm still looking for information concerning Apps, but I the policy with Apps is either the same or more restrictive.